# setting up rclone config programmatically with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, rclone

I am trying to simplify the rclone config with a batch file so that an end-user does not need to use the command line at all. I want that an end-user only enters the login details to browser window that rclone config opens during the config process.

I am trying to send rclone configurations parameters into it programmatically with a batch file, I want that all default settings come from a file config.txt  and then rclone only pops up the browser window to ask the cloud login credentials. I am using a batch file syntax

```
rclone config <config.txt
```

The text file CONFIG.TXT contains these commands, one/row with a linefeed:

```
n 
mydropbox 
12
 blank crlf
 blank crlf
n
y
```

When these commands are given manually to rclone, the dropbox login page appears, but from the batch file there is an error "**Failed to read line: EOF**" shown and the batch file does not work and the browser files does not appear.

> Current remotes:
>
> Name                 Type
> ====                 ====
> dropbox              dropbox
>
> e) Edit existing remote n) New remote d) Delete remote r) Rename
> remote c) Copy remote s) Set configuration password q) Quit config
> e/n/d/r/c/s/q>
>
> name>
>
> 2022/10/13 07:19:23 Failed to read line: EOF

How to solve the issue, so that I can deliver to customers a batch file that preconfigures the dropbox and only opens the browser window to ask login details?

Or is it a better method to write the .conf file by batch file and set the env var  RCLONE_CONFIG, or perhaps to use somehow remote setup procedure described at https://rclone.org/remote_setup/, but how?